# Is there any way to identify which posts use which gutenberg blocks?

Tags: block-editor

Is there any way to list/report out which posts use a specific Gutenberg block in the post - almost like a 'search blocks' feature?

I run a blog with about 1000 posts, and recently, one of the Gutenberg blocks plugins that I use has become incompatible with my theme, so I needed to disable it.

I now have a large number of posts that I need to update and change any of the posts that used blocks supplied by the now-disabled plugin to use the more generic WP-supplied blocks.

Does WP have a straightforward way to identify which posts have these blocks so I can avoid 'editing' every single post on my blog just to see if the invalid blocks are present?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I'm new to SE, so if this is in the wrong area or doesnt belong here, just let me know.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you and this sounds like a super frustrating predicament, but in earnest, this is why I'm always so hesitant to use third-party solutions on WP sites, then you're left to the whims of the other developer.
If you can identify one post that uses that block and check via phpMyAdmin to see if there is a unique identifying trait to it in the post content in the database, then you may be able to get a full list using SQL queries.  Can you check and let me know?

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  Let me dig into it and see what I can find.